# Why is my display:inline-block; property displaying in top-to-bottom and not left-to-right?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dynamic layout of divs that use display:inline-block, to help fit the content, since it could be different heights.

Here is the code I am using, but for some reason, my divs display like

```
1357
2468
```

Rather than

```
1234
5678
```

Code I am using:

```
article{
 -moz-column-width: 13em;
 -webkit-column-width: 13em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em; 

}

section{
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  0.25rem;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
 background:  #efefef;
}
```

and here is my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om4qc3g2/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `column` CSS property, who display elements in "columns" from top to bottom.

To get a horizontal behavior, you can use `display: inline-block` or use JS plugin such as masonry.

[Fiddle with inline-block aligment](https://jsfiddle.net/om4qc3g2/2/)

Comment: Yeah I know about masonry, but was trying to recreate it with only CSS. I guess my solution would be to actually just use Masonry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `inline-flex`? I created this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PCrews/om4qc3g2/5/)

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't handle the heights in the way that I wanted.